# Dataframe merge based on all the columns of subset dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a superset dataframe and subset dataframe. Superset has n number of columns and subset has m (n > m).

Requirement is to compare m columns of subset with matching columns headings from the superset.

**Note**: dataframes contained data from csv files, subset being reference file and superset being the whole tool output file.
And, both the dataframes will vary based on the requirement under test.

**e.g.1.**

Superset columns:

```
Car_Brand, Car_model, Color, Year, Engine
```

Subset columns:

```
Year, Engine
```

I have to log failure if the entries of 'Year' 'Engine' are not matching between both the dataframes.

**e.g.2:**

Superset columns:

```
Car_Brand, Car_model, Color, Year, Engine, Country, Rating, Price
```

Subset columns:

```
Car_model, Rating, Price
```

I have to log failure if the entries of Car_model, Rating, Price are not matching between both the dataframes.

There are 100s of such different cases, need to write generic way to merge superset & subset based on the column names of subset.

How can I achieve this?

Something like:

```
common_df = superset_df.merge(subset_df, on=subset_df.columns[0], how='inner')
```

Comment: This is what I used finally, simple and precise,  common_df = superset_df[list(subset_df.columns.values)]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help even if the subset dataframe has variable column numbers, and the same columns are present in Superset dataframe.

```
superset = {'Car_Brand':['mahi01','ta02','suz03','hon04','hyu05','ki06'],
            'Car_model':['xu01','nex02','bal03','ama04','cre05','son06'], 
            'Color':['white','blue','red','grey','black','beige'], 
            'Year':['2018','2019','2020','2021','2022','2017'],
            'Engine':['ab01','ab02','ab03','ab04','ab05','ab06']}

dfSuper = pd.DataFrame(superset, columns=['Car_Brand', 'Car_model', 'Color',
                                 'Year', 'Engine'])
```

```
subset = {'Year':['2018','2010','2020','2021','2020'],
          'Engine':['ab01','ab02','ab03','ab04','ab05']}
dfSub = pd.DataFrame(subset, columns=(['Year', 'Engine']))
```

```
df3Result = dfSuper.merge( dfSub, on=list(dfSub.columns.values), how='left', indicator='match')
df3Result['match'] = np.where(df3Result.match == 'both', True, False)
```

[image: dfSuper:]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Arpan. I got some idea, though my requirement is bit complex but this would definitely help.

Comment: This is what I used finally, simple and precise,  common_df = superset_df[list(subset_df.columns.values)]